# What is the relationship between an Android background service, MainApplication, and ActivityLifecycleCallbacks?

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out how life cycles are supposed to work on Android between the main application of an Android app, some declared background services, an how they are initialized. I think I've boiled my confusion down to a few points that I don't have answers for. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- Is the main application of an app (generated as MainApplication.java typically) always created if a service is launched from the same app in the background?
- Is a ActivityLifecycleCallbacks in your MainApplication (hooked up with registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks) the right way to initialize something that your app and your background service both depend on?

Comment: please read this :https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely good to have. It doesn't really answer the higher level questions though.